# Using echo with lists in php?

Tags: php, list, echo

I have the following PHP code:

```
$getnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getnews)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $title = $row['title'];
  $body = $row['body'];
  $date = $row['date'];
  echo "<div class=\"title\">$title</div><br>";
  echo nl2br($body);
  echo "<br><div class=\"date_time\">".time_ago($date)."</div>";
  echo "<hr>";
}
```

This is used to create a news feed and  I use echo to print out what is within the updates.
Is there a way in which I could maybe use a list to print out each update instead of the way im currently doing it?

Or is it possible to create a div around each update that the while loop creates?

*I'm sorry if the question is not clear but thanks for all the help!*

My newsfeed creates updates in a news feed like twitter. Each update is printed out using echo and surrounded by

---

. Im trying to find a way in which I can create a list or div for the entire layout of each update. Im finding very difficult to arrange whats going on in each update.

Comment: It's not clear what your trying to achieve sorry.

Comment: What do you mean use a list to print out updates? Are you trying to achieve some styling effect? Are you trying to use a list HTML tag?

Comment: Yes im trying to do this for styling reasons. I updated my query above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should get you there. Just echo out the html as you would like it to appear.

```
$getnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getnews)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    echo "<div class='news-article'>";
    echo "<div class=\"title\">$title</div><br>";
    echo nl2br($body);
    echo "<br><div class=\"date_time\">".time_ago($date)."</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

A lot of the time a lot of echo statements like that just confuse what you are trying to do.

```
$getnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getnews)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    ?>
    <div class='news-article'>
    <div class="title"><?php echo $title ?></div><br>
    <?php echo nl2br($body); ?>
    <br><div class="date_time"><?php echo(time_ago($date)) ?></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <?php
}
```

If you wanted to accomplish the same thing as an unordered list you would do this.

```
$getnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<ul class='article-list'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getnews)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    ?>
    <li class='news-article'>
    <div class="title">$title</div><br>
    <?php echo nl2br($body); ?>
    <br><div class="date_time"><?php echo(time_ago($date)) ?></div>
    </li>

    <?php
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That should get me going in the right direction!